# What's the name of this Robotech song?

Tags: music, robotech

When I was younger, I knew the Robotech Perfect Soundtrack perfectly. The RPS had most of the Robotech songs, and for a long time most fans thought it had all songs. Later some songs were pointed out not to be in the RPS and to the in the 80's series and movies (no new songs were added for a period of 20 years, since no animation appeared for 20 years), but this one I don't remember it at all. I don't think it was in the RPS. Which is the name of this song?

[Robotech 2014 original soundtrack](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dduwy5we7dM&t=7m7s)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is "The Right Move" sung by Minmei, only once, on the radio in episode 18 of the Macross Saga. It's featured in CD2 of the 20th anniversary OST. Deculture it is not.